# build an xml document from FieldStorage post data python

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, post

I have some form post data that I have converted to a dict. I want to turn this dict into an xml document. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this. 
Previously I have tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, cgitb



def cgiFieldStorageToDict( fieldStorage ):
   # Makes a dictionary from the http post data
   params = {}
   for key in fieldStorage.keys():
      params[ key ] = fieldStorage[ key ].value
   return params


dict = cgiFieldStorageToDict( cgi.FieldStorage() )

print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print
print
print'''xml<configuration>
    <location name="location">
        <latitude>54.637348</latitude>
        <latHemi>true</latHemi>
        <longitude>5.829723</longitude>
        <longHemi>true</longHemi>
    </location>
    <microphone name="microphone">
        <sensitivity>-26.00</sensitivity>
    </microphone>
    <weighting name="weighting">'''
if dict['aWeight'] == 'true':
    print'<aWeight>true</aWeight>'
else:
     print'<cWeight>true</cWeight>'
print'''</weighting>
    <optionalLevels name="optionalLevels">
        <L95>false</L95>
        <L90>false</L90>
        <L50>false</L50>
        <L10>false</L10>
        <L05>true</L05>
        <fmax>false</fmax>
    </optionalLevels>
 </configuration>'''
```

With the vague idea that if all the outputs matched what I expected then I could convert or overwrite the old xml file. This is not working. No matter how I change the if / else statement it just won't work. Any ideas would be very grateful or if anyone knows of anyway to convert form post data to an xml file or overwrite an old xml file with form post data I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

I have found a way of turning a dict into xml but it is not working for me. I assume it is because it is post data. It's handy to know for future reference in case anyone ever needs it. This is not my code, it is copy and pasted from the python cookbook.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

 # Convert dict into xml
def dict_to_xml(tag, d):
    elem = Element(tag)
    for key, val in d.items():
        child = Element(key)
        child.text = str(val)
        elem.append(child)
    return elem
```

Comment: why else:
     print'<cWeight>true</cWeight>'? you had set always true value for aWeight.

Comment: @giaosudau It is set that way from the form data. Other times it will be false depending on what the user does with the form. This dict is based on what the user does with a form.